# Github CoPilot error - The extension is not installable on any current installed products

Tags: github-copilot

I have Visual Studio community 2022 Version 17.5.1 and when I try to install GitHub co-pilot I get the following error:
**   The extension is not installable on any current installed products.**

### Below is the full error log:

```
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - 17.5.4065+gbda5f544dc
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - Command line parameters:
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Community,/skuVersion:17.5.33424.131,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\stan\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXghffgjr3.vsix
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - Initializing Install...
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM - Extension Details...
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   Identifier         : GitHub.Copilot
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   Name               : GitHub Copilot
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   Author             : GitHub
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   Version            : 1.94.0.0
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   Description        : GitHub Copilot is an AI pair programmer that helps you write code faster and with less work. Requires Visual Studio 2022 17.5.5 or later.
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   Locale             : en-US
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   MoreInfoURL        : 
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   InstalledByMSI     : False
8/3/2023 9:44:29 PM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   SignatureState     : ValidSignature
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   SignedBy           : GitHub, Inc.
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   Certificate Info   : 
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       -------------------------------------------------------
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       [Subject]       : CN="GitHub, Inc.", O="GitHub, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       [Serial Number] : 0ED17E3276477EECDEDE0A65744ABC0E
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       [Not Before]    : 2/9/2023 6:00:00 PM
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       [Not After]     : 2/13/2024 5:59:59 PM
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       [Thumbprint]    : 0C5C3D5588A23CC0B287C00262D03CC3F6F4A7FB
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   Supported Products : 
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -           Version : [17.5.33627,18.0)
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -           ProductArchitecture : amd64
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   References         : 
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   Prerequisites      : 
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       -------------------------------------------------------
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       Name         : IntelliCode
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -       Version      : [17.4.33213,18.0)
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM - Signature Details...
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM -   Extension is signed with a valid signature.
8/3/2023 9:44:30 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack, IDictionary`2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

tried reinstalling it and could not find any suggestions in StackOverflow.

Comment: I was able to fix it by installing Visual Studio 17.7.1